# Can you repair a load bearing header from the outside of the house by removing the outer most 2"x12" without supporting the beam that the header rests

Tags: framing

Can you repair a load bearing header from the outside of the house by removing the outer most 2"x12" without supporting the beam that the header rests

Comment: Depends on the load on the beam. If the inner most 2x12 is not over stressed, then it can carry the load. Are there joists resting on the beam? What is the span of the 2x12’s and how many floors rest on the beam and are you going to do the work with snow on the roof?

Comment: Its a 2 story house. The header is above a French door in the walk out basement. The main beam of the house rests on top of this header. There is some wood rot on the outside trim and the part of the header. Can just the outer 2x12 be replaced from the outside without building a support for the beam on the inside?

Comment: Can you fashion a temporary support, like using a jack or some cribbing, while you repair/replace the suspect outer beam? I don't understand why you are asking about not supporting the load...

Comment: What is the span of the joists from the outside beam to it’s inside support… on both floors.

Comment: Builders usually do not use extra 2x12s unless they are needed to support loads safely.  You are planning to temporary remove maybe half of a support structure that holds up your house.  It might hold, but good chance it will crack if it does not have extra support.

Comment: This question is both vague and opinion-based. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

**NO**

The two 2x12s should have been very thoroughly nailed together (with a piece of 1/2" plywood or OSB sandwiched in between to make the thickness correct for the wall<sup>*</sup>) when they were installed. You won't be able to get just one of them separated from the other from the outside. Once you've got the whole header removed, you might not be able to separate the two of them and have one still be salvageable and reusable - you might have to replace both. Prepare to replace both and be happily surprised if you only have to replace one.

You're going to have to build temporary bracing for the ceiling above. The good news is that you're in the basement, so you won't have to build any support below this - the ground will support the slab which will support the floors above.

---

<sup>*</sup>One 2x12 is 1.5" thick, two together are 3" thick. A standard 2x4" wall is 3.5" thick. When headers are built for a 2x4 wall, an extra layer of 1/2" plywood/OSB is sandwiched between the two pieces of dimensional lumber so the total thickness matches up with the thickness of the studs it's resting on. This way, you've got a nice flush surface inside for drywall and outside for siding.

If your house was built with 2x6 studs, then the wall is 5.5" thick and you'd have a tripled header (3 times 1.5" is 4.5") plus two layers of 1/2" plywood.

Comment: While you're right about the construction techniques, it certainly _can_ be done. One strategy would be to slice the 2x12 vertically into strips, making them fairly easy to break out in chunks.

Comment: Can be done (separated?) in situ, @isherwood, or once the complete header's been removed from the wall? If you're suggesting that it could be cut into strips while still in the wall, I'd really like to know your proposal for doing so because I'm not coming up with anything that would work without causing additional damage to the wall above/below. I'm sure your experience is vastly superior to mine, so you've probably got ideas I just haven't come up with.

Comment: You'd just run a circular saw down it as far as possible, then hit the edge with a recipro saw. I'm not saying it would be easy, but I've replaced many a rim joist and other components that way. Keep in mind that many walls nowdays are 2x6, so the header may be in a hollow U configuration.

Comment: A big hammer and a good prybar are critical. It's just wood, though. Once it's in strips it breaks up fairly easily along the grain.

Comment: Interesting, I've not heard of making a U-shaped header. I still have much to learn. Additionally, since this is a basement, the header may be supported by concrete/CMU on the ends, and caution should be taken to not cut into the top of the french door unit and damage it if attempting to remove it in place.